# Google-Maps-for-Rails gem, Force Geocoding of Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

How do I force [Google-Maps-for-Rails](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails) gem to geocode a model? I dont' want to re-geocode every member, just some.

Along those lines, once a model member has been geocoded and the lon/lat stored in the db, how do I clear that so it re-geocodes?

Could be the same answer for both questions, I don't know.

Comment: +1 for the bug I discovered thanks to your question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Your question raised a problem in the gem: it geocoded after each save, not checking the boolean reference. It's fixed now in 0.4.1*

### By default

- Geocoding is made as part of the save process.
- if the boolean `gmaps == true`, then geocoding is skipped
- else the geocoding is done

You can configure it the way you want.

BTW, you could even use the geocoding function:

```
Gmaps4rails.geocode('your address')
```

And saves directly the values you want.

See doc here: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Methods

Answer (score 0):

you might also want to try the [geocoder gem](http://www.rubygeocoder.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to an existing database, I wanted to geocode on access, and then cache the result.  So I added an accessor function for latitude and longitude that checks for a value, and if the database doesn't have it, Geocode and save, and then return the value.  This way, it gets geocoded "on demand".